# Redirecting directories in home partition

Tags: partitioning, ssd, symbolic-link, home-directory, sd-card

I have a 60GB SSD for my / filesystem but for more space I got a 16GB SD card for my /home partition. I'm worried it won't be able to take the amount to write the /home directory. So I was wondering if it would be a good idea to sys-link some directories to a home2 directory I have made in the / partition and I wanted to know what directories I should link.

I have already done this with downloads but should I do this using `.~/cache` or `.~/config`?

Answer (score 0):

The lower bound for write accesses to flash memory is said to be 100 000 cycles. So for most usages of your home partition, this means they are no problem.

How long do you need to write 16 GB to your home? If you fill the whole drive 30 times per day, you can repeat this procedure 10 years, where the price for such a storage will be about Nothing.

Do you have frequent write access for many, big files? In the end, only yourself can answer the question. The firefox-cache in /home/YOURNAME/.mozialla/firefox is something, which is changed frequently, but if it could be a problem depends on your surf habits.

```
find  /home/YOURNAME/.mozilla/firefox -mtime -1 -ls
```

will show you how many files and how big there are, younger than one day. Daily work on big, raw images could be another issue, but 100 000 writes are a lot, and sometimes it is said to be 5 000 000 writes.

If 95% of the drive is statically filled, and the dynamic writes/deletes happen to affect always the same 5% of the drive, the lifespan in only 5%.